# mongoose: what is the purpose of Query#exec

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The [Query#exec](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) method of Mongoose says it executes the query and returns a Promise object. What I don't understand is why this is required, as there already is a [Query#then](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec#query_Query-then) method.

Concrete Example:

Consider some simple model

```
var Foo = mongoose.model("Foo", {name: String});
```

What would be the difference between

```
Foo.find().then(
  function(res){ /* .. */ },
  function(err) { /* .. */ }
);
```

and

```
Foo.find().exec().then(
  function(res){ /* .. */ },
  function(err) { /* .. */ }
);
```

Both seem to work properly.

Comment: first first first shouldn't give you the correct quest result..

Comment: @Shih-MinLee sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Can you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query.exec(function(err, result))` has been present forever in mongoose. It allows to pass a callback AND in newer versions of mongoose also returns a promise. Lots of code (old and new) still uses callbacks, so this is probably still more often used than the `.then()`.

the `then()` method was introduced much later, when mongoose was promisified - but old code should not be broken so `exec()` will stay forever I guess.